# finding files with same name and postfix shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, find

I have a requirement like this:

- find whether two files exist with the same name excluding the date stamp. (ex: custompayment_24APR, custompayment_25APR) in a given directory. I have files like `xxx_24Apr,xxx_25Apr... yyy_24Apr,yyy_25Apr` where xxx and yyy can be anything... How can I do that?
- append lines from file1 to file2. (_24Apr being file 1, and _25Apr being second)
- get the count of the lines which start with a particular character (character is specified).

Can someone help to come up with a shell script? If you can help finding the files part would be great and I will manage the rest.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To find and compare the file parts

```
$ file1=custompayment_24APR
$ file2=custompayment_25APR
$ echo ${file1%%_*}
custompayment
$echo ${file2%%_*}
custompayment
$ case "${file1%%_*}" in
> "${file2%%_*}" ) echo "same";;
> esac
same
```

To find last part of the file after the "_"

```
$ echo "_${file1##*_}"
_24APR
```

To count files that start will special character

```
shopt -s nullglob
echo "character*" | wc -l
```

OR using `find`

```
find . -type f -iname "character*" | wc -l
```

Comment: I have files like xxx_24Apr,xxx_25Apr... yyy_24Apr,yyy_25Apr where xxx and yyy can be anything.. How can I do that?

Comment: Can't really see well in comments. Posts your file name samples in your question

Comment: well, you want to compare the file names without the time stamp right? So my first solution does that. Have you tried that?

Comment: Not yet. That may not work because I want my script to be generic and I cant explicitly encode file names in the script because there are lot of other files in the same directory. But I have got the logic you have pointed.

Comment: well if you want to be generic, use a for loop to go through your files and do the comparison. `for file in *_*;do .... ;done`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another use for the [safe find](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh):

```
append_duplicates_to_newest()
{
    while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
    do
        prefix="${REPLY%_*}"
        if [ "$prefix" = "$old_prefix" ]
        then
            cat -- "$old_file" >> "$REPLY"
        fi
        old_file="$REPLY"
        old_prefix="$prefix"
    done 9< <( find "/path/to/files/" -type f -printf '%f\0' | sort -z)
}
```

For the last issue, assuming the character is stored in `$char`:

```
grep --count "^$char" -r /path/to/files/
```